# Expression should be MethodCallExpression error calling Expression<Action>

Tags: c#, async-await

What is the reason for the following code throwing this exception saying "Expression has to be MethodCallExpression. I thought calling an Action IS that..

```
     Action startBouncePolling = new Action(async () =>
    {

    });

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => startBouncePolling());
```

Signature of Enqueue is one parameter of `Expression<Action>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `startBouncePolling()`, you're not calling a method. `startBouncePolling` is not a method, it's a delegate. So you are actually *invoking a delegate*.

Therefore, the body of the lambda expression `() => startBouncePolling()` ends up being a `InvocationExpression`, not a `MethodCallExpression`.

If you use a method instead of a delegate, for example:

```
public async Task StartBouncePolling()
{
}
...
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => StartBouncePolling());
```

then the body would be a `MethodCallExpression`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask HOW to force this if possible because there are some other limitations that prevent me from creating this as a method. I dont know if the reason is important but just to be clear the reason is: Enqueue returns a job id, and I need that job id inside StartBouncePolling() in order to cancel the job from inside. However if I dont pass the jobid with `ref` modifier, I believe it wont update from return value of Enqueue() as the string reference would be passed as a value. Async methods cannot have ref modifiers. My method must be async.

Comment: well, you need _a_ method in order to have a MethodCallExpression. I don't know if it will do the trick for your use case, but you can  do `startBouncePolling.Invoke()` instead of `startBouncePolling()`. Then it should be a method call on the delegate type. But that might explode in other ways..

Comment: Without creating a separate method, I can declare `string jobid` inline and use it inside the action without having to pass as ref.